# Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode)

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm developing `Spring MVC Security Hibernate` example by taking a reference from http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/. In this example, I updated maven dependencies to latest versions

```
<properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.9.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.38</mysql.connector.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.6</slf4j.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.2.11.Final</hibernate.version>
        <dbcp.version>1.4</dbcp.version>
    </properties>
```

The compilation error for reference:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project spring-security-hibernate-annotation: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project spring-security-hibernate-annotation: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.execute(WarMojo.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.war.WarArchiver.initZipOutputStream(WarArchiver.java:148)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.createArchiveMain(AbstractZipArchiver.java:309)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.execute(AbstractZipArchiver.java:211)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.createArchive(AbstractArchiver.java:897)
        at org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.createArchive(MavenArchiver.java:582)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.performPackaging(WarMojo.java:243)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.execute(WarMojo.java:177)
        ... 21 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Not sure what is wrong here. Pls help.
SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**")
        .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .and().csrf()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }
}
```

AppConfig.java

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.mkyong.*" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());
        builder
        .scanPackages("com.mkyong.users.model")
        .addProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        return builder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        prop.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        prop.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return prop;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
        ds.setUsername("root");
        ds.setPassword("root");

        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager txManager() {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

UserDao.java

```
public interface UserDao {
    User findByUserName(String username);
}
```

SpringMvcInitializer.java

```
public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

SpringSecurityInitializer.java

```
public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

UserDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public User findByUserName(String username) {

        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

        users = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from User where username=?")
                .setParameter(0, username).list();

        if (users.size() > 0) {
            return users.get(0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Project Build:

```
<build>
        <finalName>SpringSecurity</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/dependency-info.html. You need to add following plugins:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This will solve the issue.